# Does android.hardware.Camera still works on all API levels?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-api-levels

I am going to be making a camera application, really simple, just add some new interface to the camera app, so nothing fancy, and I was wondering if I could still use the old `android.hardware.Camera` api since it is simpler and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should have no problem with this portion of your project.

Answer (score 0):

It might. But...

> The `android.hardware.camera2` package provides an interface to individual camera devices connected to an Android device. **It replaces the deprecated `Camera` class**. - [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

It was deprecated as of API 21

Comment: My guess is that so long as I am not doing something that fancy, I should be ok, but my concern is that it would simply not work on say Lollipop and up or something

Comment: Only way to know would be to try and test, I suppose.